# Identify conflicts within rows grouped by a Unique ID

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataset with multiple duplicated rows, resembling:

```
UniqueID = c(111, 111, 222, 222, 333, 333)
Color = c("Yellow", "Yellow", "Blue", "Blue", "Green", "Pink")
Height = c(11, 12, 22, 23, 33, 33)

df = data.frame(UniqueID, Color, Height)
```

Within a group of rows *sharing the same Unique ID* I would like to be able to highlight any conflicting data (i.e. data which is not identical).

For example, in the above table there are three groups as defined by their unique ID. `111,222 and 333`.

Within each group I would like to highlight conflicting data. For example, in group `111` I would highlight that the height is different (11 vs 12). In group `222` I would also highlight height. However, within group `333` I would highlight color (Green vs Pink)

My plan was to use the `library(DT)` to color the cells so I can at least have a visual representation of where the conflicts are arising and then start assessing how to resolve them.

The end result would look something like:

[image]

I have been using `duplicated` thus far to remove duplicates within a column but struggling to work out how to approach this problem. The only method I can think at the moment is to subset all of the data into individual df's based on the unique ID and then highlight duplicates within each df but with 11,000 rows this seems to be very unwieldy.

A point in the direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: Define duplicate.

Comment: I was trying to work out how I could word the question title better. It is more clear in the question itself. I am defining a duplicate row as one with the same Unique ID. Then within this "duplicate" row I want to identify whether all the data is the same or if there is conflicting data

Comment: Are you trying to highlight duplicates in `Height` within groups of `UniqueID`? Or cases within groups of `UniqueID` where all `Height` values are the same?

Comment: Within a group of Unique IDs I want to highlight all data which is not identical. Ill reword the question to make that clearer

Comment: Could you post an example of the desired outcome, as a table?

Comment: *"visual representation of where conflicts are"* is a lot too vague, personally. If `Height` is different but `Color` is the same, how would that visualization change when compared to same `Height` and different `Color`? With 35 columns, the combinations are a bit dizzying, making a reasonable "quick look" rather not-so-quick (or intuitive).

Comment: I have added a picture of what the desired outcome is like. I agree that it may turn out very messy if there is no pattern in the conflicts, but I suspect that most of them (in my example) are down to GPS locations being slightly different. However, its impossible to tell manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not so sure about visualizing, but one could use `group_by()` and `summarize()` to get an overview, and subsequent manipulations to find details, e.g.,

```
tbl = tibble(UniqueID, Color, Height)
n <- tbl %>%
    group_by(UniqueID) %>%
    summarize(color = list(unique(Color)), height = list(unique(Height))
```

giving

```
> n
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  UniqueID color     height
     <dbl> <list>    <list>
1      111 <chr [1]> <dbl [2]>
2      222 <chr [1]> <dbl [2]>
3      333 <chr [2]> <dbl [1]>
4      444 <chr [1]> <dbl [1]>
```

which can be queried, e.g.,

```
> filter(n, lengths(color) >=2)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  UniqueID color     height
     <dbl> <list>    <list>
1      333 <chr [2]> <dbl [1]>
> filter(n, lengths(color) >=2) %>% tidyr::unnest("color")
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  UniqueID color   height
     <dbl> <chr>   <list>
1      333 Green   <dbl [1]>
2      333 Pink    <dbl [1]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by grouping on the ID and counting its occurrence as follows;

```
library(dplyr)

# Creating data
UniqueID = c(111, 111, 222, 222, 333, 333, 444)
Color = c("Yellow", "Yellow", "Blue", "Blue", "Green", "Pink", "Brown")
Height = c(11, 12, 22, 23, 33, 33, 40)

# Creating dataframe from data
df = data.frame(UniqueID, Color, Height)

df %>%
  # Grouping by ID
  mutate(similar_rows = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(UniqueID) %>%
  # If ID exist more than once then create new variable is_duplicated set by TRUE
  mutate(is_duplicate = ifelse(n() >= 2, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  # If you wanna highlight row numbers sharing same ID
  mutate(similar_rows = paste0(similar_rows, collapse = ",")) %>%
  ungroup()

# UniqueID Color  Height similar_rows is_duplicate
# <dbl> <fct>   <dbl> <chr>        <lgl>       
# 111 Yellow     11 1,2          TRUE        
# 111 Yellow     12 1,2          TRUE        
# 222 Blue       22 3,4          TRUE        
# 222 Blue       23 3,4          TRUE        
# 333 Green      33 5,6          TRUE        
# 333 Pink       33 5,6          TRUE        
# 444 Brown      40 7            FALSE
```

Comment: a little simpler is `mutate(is_duplicate = n() >= 2)`